# где найти функции для работы с шейдерами в OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

Где должны быть определены функции для работы с шейдерами в OpenGL? В моих "GL.h" и "GLU.h" их нет.

Моя среда:
Windows 7 , NVIDIA Geforce GT610

Функция glGetString(GL_VERSION) выдает "OpenGL version:4.5.0 NVIDIA 364.72".
Все обычные функции работают нормально. У меня получилось нарисовать куб, повертеть его, наложить текстуру с помощью glBindTexture() и glTexCoord2f().

в Windows и Linux, OpenGL поставляется вместе с системой. И конечно пути там будут разные и программные реализации. Ведь в Windows идёт Microsoft реализация, в Линух хз, наверное SGI. Так вот у меня мои встроенные файлы заголовков, находятся в папке 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gl'. И почему то там нет нужных мне функций.

Comment: В какой ОС, с какими версиями?

Comment: @D-side, вот так вот! я указал это, а меня поправил великий гуру Krom Stern и убрал "лишнюю" по его мнению инфу. Простите, Windows 7, OpenGL 4.5

Comment: @D-side, буду рад хоть каким-то комментариям. Никто не хочет отвечать. Неужели у всех сразу всё работало? Или мне вобще на линухе над под OpenGL прогать.

Comment: 4.5 это где написано?

Comment: @D-side, это вывод функции glGetString(GL_VERSION)

Comment: Интересно. Тогда должен быть в `gl.h`, либо где-то несовпадение версий. Добавьте в вопрос, как выяснили версию, может, кто-то знает, в чём дело.

Comment: @D-side, в самом GL.h написано 'BUILD Version: 0004    // Increment this if a change has global effects'

Comment: Разве заголовочные файлы зависят от ОС и модели/версии GPU?

Comment: Откуда у вас эти заголовочные файлы и почему в них нет современных функций?

Comment: @KromStern, я думаю да, поскольку в Windows и Linux OpenGL поставляется вместе с системой. И конечно пути там будут разные и программные реализации. Ведь в Windows идёт Microsoft реализация, в Линух хз, наверное SGI. Так вот у меня мои файлы заголовков встроенные, находятся в папке 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gl'. И почему то там нет нужных мне функций.

Comment: Включите это в вопрос пожалуйста, это тоже часть описания ситуации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее вместе с системой идет стандартная реализация OpenGL, и в Виндах, по крайней мере, достаточно старая. При установке дров GPU, обычно, реализация обновляется до той которую тянет GPU. Это все независимо от заголовков.

Заголовки же при использовании связываются с реализацией, причем только с теми методами что в ней есть, остальное остается пустышками или прячется (и конечно если заголовки старые, то в них самих нет части новых методов).

У вас получается два варианта, либо реализация старая/порезаная, либо заголовки.

Теперь к вопросу "где найти":

- Обновляйте дрова на GPU.
- Скачайте свежие заголовки с интернета (к сожалению на C++ не могу подсказать откуда)

Comment: Дрова на карту стоят последние, уже обновлял. Я так полагаю проблема с заголовками. Буду искать, спасибо

Comment: Я их заполучил наконец! Всё оказалось так как вы сказали. Простейшим выходом стало установить себе GLEW. В glext.h который на официальном сайте можно найти все доп. функции после OpenGL1. Но эти функции обьявлены как то "загадочно" пока для меня, типа делегатов что-то вроде. Для того чтобы использовать эти функции нужно попотеть, а GLEW сделает все за вас и объявит норм. заголовки. Спасибо тем кто откликнулся.